# Modify interaction - How to get the segment which has been hovered

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using openlayers-3 [modify interaction](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/modify-features.html) to edit vector layers. When a polygon/polyline is being edited, if mouse is close to a line segment, a small circle is drawn and dragging it creates a new vertex or moves an existing vertex, depending on where on the segment I was hovering.

Now, sometimes this is very difficult to understand if I am hovering on an existing vertex, or on middle of a segment. I have thought about two solutions to the problem:

1. Highlight the segment I am hovering with a different style so that I
   can see its edges.
2. When hovering on an vertex, style the small
   circle with a different style.

Is there a way to achieve any of the two?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done changing the [interaction condition](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html) like:

```
var selectPointerMove_Highlight = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});
map.addInteraction(selectPointerMove_Highlight);
```

I have an [online example](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/f2sah3d2/).

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for. Perhaps the question was not very clear. I have edited the question. Please check if you can help.